# GridView SelectMethod Issue With WebPart Sharepoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, model-binding

**Hi every one ,**

I have a problem with a gridview in webpart sharepoint 2013 ,I use model bind with the gridview and I have assigned a select method to the gridview when I deployed the webpart it raise the following error

```
A public method with the name  was either not found or there were multiple methods 
with the same name on the type x.master
```

**thanks alot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution ,

you need to register this code within the CallingDataMethod GridView event :

```
 protected void GridView1_CallingDataMethods(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CallingDataMethodsEventArgs e)
        {
e.DataMethodsObject = this;
        }
```

and every thing will work fine

thanks